# Stratified Paired T-Test for One Group

Tags: t-test, paired-data, stratification, intervention-analysis, pre-post-comparison

I have pre/post data where all subjects underwent the intervention. The outcome is a score. I am also looking to stratify my analysis by gender. I understand I can stratify my paired t-test in SAS via a simple class statement, but how do I determine if the difference between the genders are significant? I would normally use an interaction for this but given the data is paired and I am using a t-test, i am not sure how to test the significance of the difference.

Comment: Why not just conduct a `t.test` between the original data of the two groups based upon gender (that is, not just a `t.test` between male pre and post treatment and female pre and post treatment, but pre-treatment male and female and post-treatment male and female)?

Comment: well if i would to approach it like that, i would probably need to do a t test between genders for the difference, but then do i have to adjust for baseline scores?

Comment: The `t.test` does not rely on previous estimates of the distribution.  You could also do an `F.test` through an `ANOVA`, which would be able to look at the interactions as well.

Comment: If i decided to use an F.test then would my outcome be the difference, and would I need to adjust for the (pre) scores?

Comment: I do not believe that you would need to adjust for the pre scores for either test. In either case, the test is between the subgroups and detecting if the is a statistically significant difference between the samples.